# What do the Appstats values mean?

Tags: google-app-engine, appstats

Take [these stats](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_dLfQMJsmsaI/S7NKQChvYYI/AAAAAAAAAEI/xtrznFfj05g/s1600/appstats2.png) from a [post](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/03/easy-performance-profiling-with.html) from the App Engine blog as an example:

```
real = 107ms  
cpu = 141ms  
api = 388ms  
overhead = 1ms

RPC Total: 63ms (388ms api)   
Grand Total: 107ms (530ms cpu + api)
```

I think I understand overhead: it gives the amount of time taken to write the logs, excluding the time it took to store the logs in memcache.

I am confused by the other numbers:

- What exactly do real, cpu and api mean?
- How is api different from RPC total?
- What is the "Grand Total"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my understanding:

- `real` is the time as measured by a clock.  This is time elapsed.
- `api` usage is the time spent on RPC's, such as accessing the datastore.  This is not truly a time, but some amount of computing resources measured in time.
- `cpu` usage is the time spent executing code.  Again, it's not really a time but resource usage as measured in time.
- `api` is different than `RPC Total` only in that RPC total shows the amount of clock time that has elapsed during the `api` time.  It's possible to do 388ms of computation in 63ms because of parallelism.  So, `RPC Total` shows both clock-time spent, as well as resoure usage.
- `Grand Total` is the total wall time (the same as `real`), with the sum of `cpu`, `api`, and `overhead`.  In this case, 530ms of quota are used in 107ms.
- `overhead` is, of course, time "wasted" waiting for "real" work to be done.  This mostly includes the resources taken by AppStats itself.

See the document [Appstats: RPC Instrumentation for Google App Engine](https://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0AQwBadvrXbuVZGZkM3p0czRfMTlkNjI1M2NjOQ) by Guido van Rossum for details.

Guido van Rossum gave a talk at Google I/O 2010 called [Appstats - Instrumentation for App Engine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvp7CuBWVgA) where he discusses this briefly.  It's a great talk to learn about App Engine, and optimization and instrumentation in general.  It's about an hour long.

Comment: I watched that talk one hour ago, being left me just as confused :| Do you have any other resources?

Is "clock time" the same as "time as measured by a clock"?

Do you think the explanation of overhead in my question is wrong?

Comment: Yes, clock time is time as measured by a clock.  So it "wall time".  Sorry.

I've added another -- far better -- resource that I've just found.  See the edit.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great resource!